# Make Ajax calls to the DocuSign Signature REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to get `login_information` of users using Docusign.

Getting "`The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.`"

We need to automate signing of documents in office 365 so need to write ajax rest api calls.

Does anyone has any clue on that?

Answer (score 3):

The DocuSign Signature REST API is not supported for browser clients. Eg CORS, JSONP and other techniques are not supported.

Instead, I suggest that you write a gateway in your favorite language that can accept your Ajax calls as needed, and then make the appropriate call(s) to DocuSign. The gateway will also need to handle authentication.

See the [DocuSign recipes](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes) and [reference docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/) to help you. Please submit additional questions to Stack Overflow when and if issues come up.

Thank you for developing with DocuSign.